# Process for integrating existing SaaS app with SalesForce

Tags: appexchange, saas

We have an existing SaaS app. We want to let people use SalesForce together with our app.

From a technical standpoint, we have done this via a few `Apex` classes, the `OAuth` workflow, and a few `REST API` calls. Works great!

I'm confused as to where to go now with things --

- We *do not* want to sell this integration. We already charge for our SaaS app, we just want to let people using our app already, use it together with SalesForce.
- Do we need to become a SalesForce ISV?
- Do we need to put this thing on AppExchange?
- If the REST API isn't supported for the `Professional` edition of SalesForce, how can we integrate with `Professional` editions? Do we just need to tell people if they want to integrate, they need to upgrade SalesForce to `Ultimate` or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to become a Salesforce ISV or list your app on the AppExchange. However, both of those actions offer you co-marketing opportunities that (if your SaaS business is of a certain size) your company may find very useful.

If you choose not to have a listing, you can distribute the package install link directly to your customers.

If you need to use the REST API in Professional Edition, you **will have to go through security review**, a part of the ISVforce/AppExchange program. You can learn more about that in [the ISVforce guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_api_access.htm#dev_packages_api_access).

so...You can choose if you need to support PE, or if you don't want to do the whole Partner/ISV Program dealio.

Comment: So if we want to support PE, we then DO have to do the ISV thing. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Yep. That token/whitelisting is only offered to ISV partners. But if you choose to support Enterprise Edition (not unlimited) and above, you can avoid that.